# SQL Server 2012 keyword override

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

A question for which I already know there is no pretty answer.

I have a third party application that I **cannot change**. The application's database has been converted from MS Access to SQL Server 2012. The program connects with ODBC and does not care about the backend. It sends pretty straight-forward SQL that seems to work on SQL Server nicely as well.

There is however a problem with one table that has the name "PLAN" which I already know is a SQL Server keyword.

I know that you would normally access such a table with square brackets, but since I'm *not* able to change the SQL I was wondering if there is any "ugly" hack that can either override a keyword or transform SQL on the fly.

Comment: Have you tried square brackets around the keyword? I have a table called user and I always have to: `dbo.[User]`

Comment: I deleted my answer as I see now more of what you're trying to do. The issue is that you can't change your SQL and its written as if this isn't an issue due to it being converted from access where `PLAN` is not a keyword. Now that it lives in sql where `PLAN` is a keyword and the sql is unable to changed, you need to 'override' the `PLAN` keyword. Is this accurate?

Comment: Granting that you cannot change the SQL, what then *can* you change?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to edit the third party application with a hex editor. If you find the strings PLAN, edit this to something like PPAN and then rename the table, views etc. If you catch all, it could work. But, of course it is an ugly thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are screwed I am afraid.  The only other approaches I could suggest are

1. Intercepting the network packets before it hits the SQL Server which is clearly quite complicated.  See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/server-side-query-interception-with-ms-sql-server and in particular answer https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1816
2. Decompiling the program in order to change it if it's a Java or .Net app for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're hosed. You could

- Wire up the 3rd party app to a shim MS Access database that uses [linked tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/link-tables-in-an-access-project-by-using-the-link-table-wizard-adp-HP003089371.aspx), where the Access table is nothing but a pass-through to the underlying SQL Server table. What you want to do is:

  - Change the offending column names in the SQL Server schema.
  - Create the linked tables in Access
  - Create a set of view/query in access that has the same schema that the 3rd party app expects.

  Having done that, the 3rd party app should be able to speak "Access SQL" like it always has. Access takes care of the "translation" to T-SQL. Life is good. I suspect you'll take something of a performance hit, since you're proxying everything through Access, but I don't think it'll be huge.

  That would be my preferred solution.
- The other option would be to write a "shim" DLL that implements the ODBC API and simply wraps the  actual calls to the true ODBC driver. Then capture the requests and improve them as necessary prior to invoking the wrapped DLL method. The tricky part is that your 3rd party app might be going after columns by ordinal position or might be going after them by column name. Or a mix. That means that you might need to transform the columns names on the way back, which might be more difficult than it seems.